# What are some great tools to use for keyword research?

Tags: seo, keywords, research

We've been told SEO is important and that we should conduct keyword research so that we can rank better?  What is that and what tools will help me in the process?

Answer (score 1):

Tools:

- http://www.google.com/sktool/
- http://www.google.com/trends/

Also, look for **Google's Wonder Wheel**... you might need to Google it to find it.

Answer (score 1):

There's not even a close second to [Market Samurai](http://www.marketsamurai.com/). Everything else just pales in comparison to the depth and awesomeness of this app.

Answer (score 0):

**[Wordtracker.com](http://www.wordtracker.com/) as recommended by [this article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/increased-usability)**