# Keyword research tool

Tags: seo, google-search-console, pagerank, keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some great tools to use for keyword research?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/335/what-are-some-great-tools-to-use-for-keyword-research)

In the past I've always chosen which keywords / phrases to go after by checking the traffic in the keyword tool, checking the competition for those keywords, their backlinks and PR and then by reading though all that and going on gut instinct.

I know SEOMoz has some functionality for this but are there any alternatives you could recommend ?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is Google AdWords Keyword Tool, keyworddiscovery.com & wordtracker.com.